# Ansible allow role to force create file

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a deployment script with ansible and ansistrano. My issue is when ansistrano ensures that shared paths exist :

```
- name: ANSISTRANO | Ensure shared paths exists
  file:
    state: directory
    path: "{{ ansistrano_deploy_to }}/shared/{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansistrano_shared_paths }}"
  when: ansistrano_ensure_shared_paths_exist
```

I want to force create the paths if they don't exist, but I can't modify ansistrano itself since I install the role from ansible-galaxy. So, I would like to allow the entire ansistrano role to force create a file if needed. Any idea ?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: "*Any idea?*" No. Precisely **no idea** what you ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "when" close and ansible will :

1. Look it path is present and is a directory
2. If it's not a directory, trigger an error
3. If nothing is found, create the directory